# How can I add gif to custom marker?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to add gip to image source in the marker, my app shows nothing as  marker

Here is my code....

```
<MapView
  initialRegion={region}
  maxZoomLevel={17}
  region={region}
>
  {region.latitude !== 0 ? (
    <Marker
      minDelta={0.5}
      maxDelta={2}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: region.latitude,
        longitude: region.longitude,
      }}
      title={'You are here!'}
    >
      <View style={{height: 10, width: 10}}>
        <Image 
          resizeMode="center"
          source={require('../src/images/1.gif')} 
        />
      </View>
    </Marker>
  ): null}
</MapView>
```

How i add gif to the marker??
Do i need animated marker for this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<MapView.Marker
  minDelta={0.5}
  maxDelta={2}
  coordinate={markerInfo.location}>

    <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../src/images/1.gif')} />
</MapView.Marker>
```

Comment: Do I need animated marker for it, I updated  my code in the question can you check it again Sir??? Thanks alot!

Comment: @JamalUdDin I don't think so, try it in your code

Comment: I revised my code and it did worked thanks alot

Comment: one more question when i try to resize it, its vanished. Y is that Sir ,how i resize it now??

Comment: @user14811813 did you try style?

Answer (score 0):

For `react-native-maps` you can add it as a child component like this:

```js
    <Marker
     key={id}
     coordinate={coords}
     title={title}
     onSelect={setMarker}
    >
       <Image
          source={require('../../../../assets/gifs/portal.gif')}
          style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
       />
    </Marker>
```